# 7zip: How to exclude files larger than 100mb?

Tags: command-line, 7zip

Is there a way in 7zip command line to zip folder but exclude all large files (greater than 100mb) recursively under it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are only a few files that are that big, you could write a distinctive marker like `_no7_` in their filename and use the command line version of 7zip including the switch `-xr!*_no7_*` to exclude them from archiving.
Or you can set up a list of things to exclude, e.g. filenames, and tell 7zip to use that list to determine what to exclude.
That's what I ended up doing.